# c++ array of templated abstract-base-class without breaking strict-aliasing rule

Tags: c++, arrays, inheritance, strict-aliasing, template-classes

What is the best way to create an array of objects derived from an abstract template base class without violating the strict-aliasing rule. Each derived object will define the template arguments of the base class differently but only through the constant enum value. Here is an example

```
enum  BlaEnum
{
  Bla1,
  Bla2,
  Bla3
};

template <class T, BlaEnum bla = Bla1>
class A
{
public:
   virtual void Foo() = 0;
   T att;
   BlaEnum bll;
};

class B : public A<int, BlaEnum::Bla2>
{
public:
   void Foo() override;
};

 class C : public A<int, BlaEnum::Bla3>
{
public:
   void Foo() override;
};

int main(void)
{

  B b;
  C c;

  //violates strict-aliasing rule
  A<int>* BaseArr[2] = { (A<int>*)&b,(A<int>*)&c };

}
```

Comment: instantiations with different actual type parameters are different classes, unrelated to each other (by inheritance or any other relation), notwithstanding the common template name.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `class B : public A<int, BlaEnum::Bla2>` and `class C : public A<int, BlaEnum::Bla3>` derive from different `A` that are not compatible with each other. Each of those classes causes the instantiation of a new template class (neither of which are compatible with `A<int>`).

In order to have valid common base you require a base class that does not differ in any template parameters (or is a non-template class) from the derived classes.
Modifying your example e.g.:

```
template <class T>
class Base 
{
public:
    virtual void Foo() = 0;
};

template <class T, BlaEnum bla = Bla1>
class A : public Base<T>
{
public:
   T att;
   BlaEnum bll;
};
// B and C are unchanged
int main()
{
  B b;
  C c;
  // Array of pointers to common base class
  Base<int>* BaseArr[2] = { &b,&c };
}
```

One more note: C-style arrays are not a good practice, you should prefer `std::array`(or `std::vector`) and smart pointer over raw pointers